# Reload ListFragment loaded by LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Item>>

Tags: reload, android-listfragment

How i can refresh listfragment? no tutorials from net work :( 
i have no idea, how reload this listfragment. I tried reload  by transaktionmanager, but its colide with ActionBar.TabListener, this is not support.v4. how can i retrieve new data from loadermanager and update listfragment?

Activity:

```
package sk.test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import sk.test.frags.TodoFragment;
import sk.test.prefs.EditPreferences;
import sk.test.task.DataListLoader;
import sk.test.xml.Item;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TodoFragment todoFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditPreferences.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.refresh:
                //HERE CODE FOR RELOAD todoFragment.reloadData() ????
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private boolean wantDone = false;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            todoFragment = new TodoFragment();
            this.wantDone = position == 0 ? false : true;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            args.putBoolean(TodoFragment.TASK_TYPE, this.wantDone);
            todoFragment.setArguments(args);

            return todoFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        public boolean getWantDone(){
            return this.wantDone;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.todotask_planned).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.todotask_done).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

ListFragment:

```
package sk.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

import sk.test.adapter.CustomArrayAdapter;
import sk.test.task.DataListLoader;
import sk.test.xml.Item;

/**
 * Created by Peter on 29.7.2013.
 */
public class TodoFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Item>> {

    public static String TASK_TYPE = "taskType";
    private static final String XML_SOURCE = "http://******/";
    private boolean wantDone = false;

    CustomArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("TODOLIST", "DataListFragment.onActivityCreated");

        this.wantDone = getArguments().getBoolean(TASK_TYPE);
        // Initially there is no data
        setEmptyText("No Data Here");

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Start out with a progress indicator.
        setListShown(false);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.
        Log.i("TODOLIST", "Item clicked: " + id);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<Item>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("TODOLIST", "DataListFragment.onCreateLoader");
        return new DataListLoader(getActivity(), this.wantDone);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Item>> listLoader, List<Item> items) {
        mAdapter.setData(items);
        Log.i("TODOLIST", "DataListFragment.onLoadFinished");
        // The list should now be shown.
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Item>> listLoader) {
    }

    public void reloadData(){
        //UPDATE LIST.. HOW?
    }

}
```

Loader:

```
package sk.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.util.Log;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import sk.test.commons.Commons;
import sk.test.xml.Item;
import sk.test.xml.Response;


/**
 * Created by Peter Chovan on 29.7.2013.
 */
public class DataListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Item>> {

    private List<Item> todoTasks;
    private boolean wantDone;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    public DataListLoader(Context context, boolean wantDone) {
        super(context);
        this.wantDone = wantDone;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    }



    @Override
    public List<Item> loadInBackground() {
        Log.i("TODOLIST", "DataListLoader.loadInBackground");
        String xmlData = getXmlData(prefs.getString("service_url", "http://*****/"));
        List<Item> entries = new ArrayList<Item>();

        String state = wantDone ? "WANT DONE" : "WANT PLANNED";
        if (xmlData != null) {
        xmlData = xmlData.replaceAll("<([^/]+?)/>", "<$1> </$1>");
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            try {
                Response res = serializer.read(Response.class, xmlData, false);
                for (Item i : res.getItems().getItem()) {
                    if (i.isDone() == wantDone) {
                        entries.add(i);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                for (StackTraceElement s : e.getStackTrace()) {
                    Log.e("TEST serializer", s.toString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TODOLIST DATA", "NULL");
        }

        return entries;
    }

    public String getXmlData(String uri) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user", prefs.getString("service_login", "devel"));
            params.put("pass", prefs.getString("service_password", "devel"));
            params.put("class", "GetList");
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(Commons.getRequestData(params));  //add request params
            wr.flush();

            String xmlData = readStream(con.getInputStream());

            wr.close();
            con.disconnect();
            return xmlData;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            for (StackTraceElement s : e.getStackTrace()) {
                Log.e("TODOLIST", "doInBackground" + s.toString());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line + "\n";
            }
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            for (StackTraceElement s : e.getStackTrace()) {
                Log.e("TODOLIST", "ReadStream || " + s.toString());
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    for (StackTraceElement s : e.getStackTrace()) {
                        Log.e("TODOLIST", "ReadStream || " + "Error while closing Reader");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Called when there is new data to deliver to the client.  The
     * super class will take care of delivering it; the implementation
     * here just adds a little more logic.
     */
    @Override
    public void deliverResult(List<Item> listOfData) {
        if (isReset()) {
            // An async query came in while the loader is stopped.  We
            // don't need the result.
            if (listOfData != null) {
                onReleaseResources(listOfData);
            }
        }
        List<Item> oldApps = listOfData;
        todoTasks = listOfData;

        if (isStarted()) {
            // If the Loader is currently started, we can immediately
            // deliver its results.
            super.deliverResult(listOfData);
        }

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with
        // 'oldApps' if needed; now that the new result is delivered we
        // know that it is no longer in use.
        if (oldApps != null) {
            onReleaseResources(oldApps);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to start the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (todoTasks != null) {
            // If we currently have a result available, deliver it
            // immediately.
            deliverResult(todoTasks);
        }


        if (takeContentChanged() || todoTasks == null) {
            // If the data has changed since the last time it was loaded
            // or is not currently available, start a load.
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to cancel a load.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCanceled(List<Item> apps) {
        super.onCanceled(apps);

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
        // if needed.
        onReleaseResources(apps);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

        // Ensure the loader is stopped
        onStopLoading();

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
        // if needed.
        if (todoTasks != null) {
            onReleaseResources(todoTasks);
            todoTasks = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated
     * with an actively loaded data set.
     */
    protected void onReleaseResources(List<Item> apps) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to restart the Loader: `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);`